# Run a command using arguments that come from an array

Tags: bash, bash-array

Suppose I have a graphical program named `app`. Usage example: `app -t 'first tab' -t 'second tab'` opens two 'tabs' in that program.

The question is: how can I execute the command (i.e. `app`) from within a `bash` script if the number of arguments can vary?

Consider this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tabs=(
    'first tab'
    'second tab'
)

# Open the app (starting with some tabs).
app  # ... How to get `app -t 'first tab' -t 'second tab'`?
```

I would like the above script to have an effect equivalent to `app -t 'first tab' -t 'second tab'`. How can such a bash script be written?

Edit: note that the question is asking about composing command line arguments on the fly using an array of arguments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Giving the arguments from an array is easy, `"${array[@]}"` expands to the array entries as distinct words (arguments). We just need to add the `-t` flags. To do that, we can loop over the first array, and build another array for the full list of arguments, adding the `-t` flags as we go:

```
#!/bin/bash
tabs=("first tab" "second tab")
args=()
for t in "${tabs[@]}" ; do 
    args+=(-t "$t")
done
app "${args[@]}"
```

Use `"$@"` instead of `"${tabs[@]}"` to take the command line arguments of the script instead of a hard coded list.

Related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: This won't quote args that have spaces. It's not the same.

Comment: @ygoe, I'm not sure what you're comparing against. Quoting really only means anything when a shell command line is first processed. After that, it's better to think of shell "words" or the arguments that go to the command the shell runs (shell "words" can contain whitespace, so it's a somewhat confusing term). The array expansion like `"${args[@]}"` expands each element of the array to a separate word/argument, so the above works like `app -t "first tab" -t "second tab"`. If there's some corner case where it fails, please do tell.

Answer (score 6):

```
tabs=("-t" "one tab" "-t" "second tab")
echo app "${tabs[@]}"
app -t one tab -t second tab
```

So now you should convert your original array to array with "-t" flags. Hope it's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh -
tabs=(
    'first tab'
    'second tab'
)

app -t$^tabs
```

That calls `app` as if you had entered:

```
app -t'first tab' -t'second tab'
```

`rc`, `es` and `fish` do that implicitly (zsh's `$^array` is actually inspired from `rc`'s `^`):

In those shells,

```
app -t$tabs
```

would do that as well. In zsh, you can get that behaviour as well by default by turning the `rcexpandparam` option on with `set -o rcexpandparam`.

In ksh93, bash and zsh, you can also use the `${array[@]/pattern/replacement}` operator from ksh93:

```
#! /bin/bash -
tabs=(
    'first tab'
    'second tab'
)

app "${tabs[@]/#/-t}"
```

Where we replace the (zero-width) start of each element with `-t`, so in effect prepending `-t` to each.

To call `app` as if with

```
app -t 'first tab' -t 'second tab'
```

as opposed to

```
app -t'first tab' -t'second tab'
```

That is where `-t` and `first tab` are two different arguments to `app`, with `zsh`:

```
app ${${:--t}:^^tabs}
```

using the `${array1:^^array2}` *array-zipping* operator where `${:--t}` (minimal form of `${var:-default}`) is used to *inline* the first array.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is explicitely about Bash, so "it’s easier with [something that’s not Bash]" is not a valid answer.

Comment: @bfontaine, I've  now added an approach which also works in bash for those people coming here and are constrained to using bash. In any case, note that answers here are not intended only for the OP, but anyone with similar requirement and not everyone is stuck with bash, you'll find that giving alternatives is generally encouraged rather than frowned upon.

Answer (score -3):

Basically the following `bash` script will read the file which include sites line by line and open each site in a new tab.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do 
    xdg-open "$line"
done < /root/file
```

> Usage

`./script.sh sites`

Comment: Ah but you are running the command (`xdg-open` in your case) multiple times. I would like the command to be run only once.

Comment: The question is about getting the arguments from an array, not a file.